# Format phone number based on regular expression dynamically

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I need to format and update in real time `UITextField` to match given **regular expression** when user is typing and pre filled it with proper character (for example hyphen).

For example: when format should be `###-###-####` and regular expression `^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$`, then hyphen should be added to `UITextField` dynamically, after typed third and seventh digit.

It must be extensible for different regular expressions in the future.

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: You can check https://github.com/Serheo/SHSPhoneComponent.
I have used it, but the format should be given in "#". For other than #, we may need to check code and modify accordingly.

Comment: That library is great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look in `UITextField` delegate method `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`, and you can put condition in it that current `range.location` is `3 or 7` then add `hyphen` at that place and add current string to next it!

Comment: Yeah, but I need to add hyphens based on regular expression. If regular expression change, then hyphen places will also change.

Answer (score 0):

**You can Use this code add delegate method for textfield**

```
  - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSInteger moddedLength = textField.text.length-(range.length-string.length);
    if (moddedLength >= 13) {
        return NO;
    }
    if (range.length == 0 &&![[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[string characterAtIndex:0]]) {
        return NO;
    }
    if ([self range:range ContainsLocation:3] || [self range:range ContainsLocation:7]|| [self range:range ContainsLocation:9])
    {
        textField.text = [self formatPhoneString:[textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string]];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

**Added this formatted method**

```
-(NSString*) formatPhoneString:(NSString*) preFormatted
{
    NSString* workingString = [preFormatted stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
    if(workingString.length > 3) {
        workingString = [workingString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(3, 0) withString:@"-"];
    }
    if(workingString.length > 7)
    {
        workingString = [workingString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(7, 0) withString:@"-"];
    }
    if(workingString.length >11)
    {
        workingString = [workingString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(3, 0) withString:@"-"];
    }
    return workingString;

}

-(bool) range:(NSRange) range ContainsLocation:(NSInteger) location {
    if(range.location <= location && range.location+range.length >= location)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need it to work with regular expressions. That solution only works for one case.

Comment: You can use this it may be work this  regular expressions.  @"^\\d{3}[-]\\d{3}[-]\\d{4}$"

Comment: Yes, but what with the other ones? I need it to work with many different regular expressions. Not only one.

Comment: You can check this link there are sample code for regular expressions according to your formate  (https://www.raywenderlich.com/30288/nsregularexpression-tutorial-and-cheat-sheet)